# How to run BB10 simulator in Mac OS X

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10

After installing the simulator I am not able to follow the instructions found [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/simulator_installing.html). I installed BlackBerry 10 Dev Alpha B Simulator. The page asks to run "BlackBerry10Simulator-BB10_ n_nn" but I cannot find any thing like that in my installation directory:

```
ls -1 BlackBerry10Simulator-BB10_0_10-261/
BlackBerry10Simulator-BB10_0_10.vmwarevm
bbm
controllers
install
```

I found "runBB10Simulator.sh" in the bbm directory but running it does not actually run a simulator, I am not sure what it does.

```
$ls -1 BlackBerry10Simulator-BB10_0_10-261/bbm
KeyNego.SIMULATOR.keystore
README.txt
Servers
bin
classpath
licenses
runBB10Simulator.sh
shutdown.sh
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

The simulator requires VMWare player, a free download.

http://www.vmware.com/products/player/

Cheers

EDIT:
Mac OS requires http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html which is not free. Either bootcamp windows, install a linux distro or virtualize either to virtualize the emulator... (XZibit meme someone?) which is likely not going to work.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not finding any player for Mac OS X. I looked for one here: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/5_0|PLAYER-501|product_downloads

Comment: Once upon a time I've virtualised Windows Phone on virtualised Windows on 32GB card... The biggest problem - running out of space.

Answer (score 3):

MAC OS requires VMFusion 30 day trial for installing the BB 10 simulator.

Answer (score 1):

@russoue:- Once you install VMware Fusion Just open the `**BlackBerry10Simulator-BB10_0_10.vmwarevm**` with VMware Fusion and you are done. it will take some 5 min to load simulator.